# adding a new item in list adds last value added to list on previous index

Tags: c#, list

This is my code that is supposed to add object value to list.

```
public List<tempTable> GetAttendanceLeaveReportForChart(double totalWorkingdays, double attendanceDays, double leaveData, double absentData) 
{       
    List<tempTable> temp = new List<tempTable>();
    for (int ct = 0; ct < 4; ct++)
    {
        if (ct == 0) 
        {
            tempTable tempTableForAttendAndLeaveReport = new tempTable();          
            tempTableForAttendAndLeaveReport.FieldName = "Total working days";
            tempTableForAttendAndLeaveReport.FieldValue = Convert.ToDouble(totalWorkingdays);
            temp.Add(tempTableForAttendAndLeaveReport); 
        }
        else if (ct == 1)
        {
            tempTable tempTableForAttendAndLeaveReport = new tempTable(); 
            tempTableForAttendAndLeaveReport.FieldName = "Attendance"; 
            tempTableForAttendAndLeaveReport.FieldValue = Convert.ToDouble(attendanceDays); 
            temp.Add(tempTableForAttendAndLeaveReport); 
        }
        else if (ct == 2)
        {
            tempTable tempTableForAttendAndLeaveReport = new tempTable();
            tempTableForAttendAndLeaveReport.FieldName = "Leave"; 
            tempTableForAttendAndLeaveReport.FieldValue = Convert.ToDouble(leaveData); 
            temp.Add(tempTableForAttendAndLeaveReport); 
        }
        else if (ct == 3) 
        {
            tempTable tempTableForAttendAndLeaveReport = new tempTable();
            tempTableForAttendAndLeaveReport.FieldName = "Absent";
            tempTableForAttendAndLeaveReport.FieldValue = Convert.ToDouble(absentData); 
            temp.Add(tempTableForAttendAndLeaveReport); 
        }
    }     
    return temp;
}
```

Here, I have created a class name `tempTable` that will store value. The value received from `tempTableForAttendandLeaveReport` will receive the value and store in list. The problem is as for loop iterates for first time, the value in `tempTable` is:

```
FieldName = "Total Working days"
```

and `fieldValue` is from variable received from argument. But as loop iterated second time, the value received at first loop is overwritten in the list .i.e. at second iteration, the value at list index 0 and 1 is the latest value added to list. 
I do not have idea of how this is happening...

Any help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at your current code, you don't need a loop, you are never using the value of `ct` and you don't need the `if`-statements. To achieve the same result, this is the only code you need:

```
public List<tempTable> GetAttendanceLeaveReportForChart(double totalWorkingdays, double attendanceDays, double leaveData, double absentData) 
{       
    List<tempTable> temp = new List<tempTable>();
    temp.add(new tempTable("Total working days", Convert.ToDouble(totalWorkingdays));
    //and etc for other 3 values
    return temp;
}
```

Given that you have a constructor in tempTable to set the two values.

**Solution**

The issue was that the field values of tempTable were `static` so always held the last value assigned to them. The fields should not have been static.

Comment: i did exactly this. still temp returns 4 list with all field name as "Absent" and field value as absentData.

Comment: public class tempTable
{
 private static string _FieldName;
    private static double _FieldValue;

    public string FieldName
    {
        get { return _FieldName; }
        set { _FieldName = value; }
    }

    public double FieldValue
    {
        get { return _FieldValue; }
        set { _FieldValue = value; }
    }
}

Comment: Your fields are `static`, which means they only have one value for all instances of tempTable - which is the last value assigned to them. Remove the `static` keyword and it will work.

Comment: oh man... DJ_polly, thanks a lot.. I was scratching my head for 2 days. thanks a lot..

Comment: upvoted for asking about `tempTable` class and identifying actual issue.

Comment: Hassan, I am new here. So i do not know how to vote. It would be grateful if you send me a link so voting ways.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to create new variable of TempTable with different name or just use re-instantiated the object. Here you don't need if-condition as you are not `ct` mentioned in the `for-loop`:

For better readability don't use lengthy variables:

```
 public List<tempTable> GetAttendanceLeaveReportForChart(double totalWorkingdays, double attendanceDays, double leaveData, double absentData) 
 { 
     List<tempTable> temp = new List<tempTable>();

     tempTable obj = new tempTable();          
     obj.FieldName = "Total working days";
     obj.FieldValue = Convert.ToDouble(totalWorkingdays);
     temp.Add(obj);        

     obj = new tempTable(); 
     obj.FieldName = "Attendance"; 
     obj.FieldValue = Convert.ToDouble(attendanceDays); 
     temp.Add(obj); 

     obj = new tempTable();
     obj.FieldName = "Leave"; 
     obj.FieldValue = Convert.ToDouble(leaveData); 
     temp.Add(obj);    

     obj = new tempTable();
     obj.FieldName = "Absent";
     obj.FieldValue = Convert.ToDouble(absentData); 
     temp.Add(obj);        

     return temp;
}
```

**UPDATE**:

```
public class tempTable 
{ 
   private string _FieldName;   //don't use static
   private double _FieldValue;  //don't use static
   public string FieldName { get { return _FieldName; } set { _FieldName = value; } }
   public double FieldValue { get { return _FieldValue; } set { _FieldValue = value;} }     
}
```

Comment: i did exactly this. still temp returns 4 list with all field name as "Absent" and field value as absentData.

Answer (score 1):

Change the Variable name then it will work.

Comment: "tempTableForAttendAndLeaveReport "